# How to analyze a nonsquare matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

The question is quite simple to write. If given a square matrix, we could analyze it by its eigenvalue and eigenvector? How about if the matrix is not squared? 
I want to know whether one nonsquare matrix has something like eigenvalue and eigenvector? A nonsquare matrix can be analyzed by something like a ellipse (in $R^2$)?

Comment: "Analyze" is a broad term. Can you be more specific about what you want? There are various ways of [representing / decomposing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition) nonsquare as well as square matrices, for example, and that's probably what you want. (Others: can we please wait until after explanations to an OP are given before downvoting a sincere question that presents itself as likely relatively easy to clarify?)

Comment: The closest thing to eigenvalues for non-square matrices would probably be [singular values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value).

Answer (score 1):

The notion of eigenvector refers to a vector whose image is related (linearly dependent) to *itself* (whence the "eigen"); at the very least this requires that the vector and its image live in the *same* vector space. A non-square matrix represents a linear map between spaces of different dimensions, which therefore cannot possibly be the same space (even a square matrix does not *have to* represent a linear map from a space to *itself*, but at least it can do so, preferably using the same basis of the same space to express the matrix in). In short, there is simply no way to have a notion of eigenvector for rectangular matrices.